# How to make Python object pre-compute a property if the property is currently None?

Tags: python, oop, properties

I am writing a Python object for storing some data. One of the data that I would like to be associated with the object has to be computed in a stochastic fashion (it is a "null model" of sorts). Therefore, I would like the function to do the following:

- If property has not been pre-computed, compute and store that property.
- If property has been pre-computed, read it from memory instead of computing.

A very, very simple toy example of what I am trying to accomplish is as follows. Suppose I have an object called Object. It is currently set up as follows:

```
from random import random

class Object(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self):
        self._x = random() # Assume that this is the stochastic thing to compute.
```

What I would like to achieve is this:

```
>> O = Object()
>> print O.x
<result of computation printed here, rather than "None">
```

Is this possible to do? If so, how would I achieve this? If not, what would be the best way for me to write the code?

Comment: The function being decorated by `@x.setter` isn't defined properly right now. It should be take a value that the client is trying to set `x` to: `def x(self, new_x): self._x = new_x`. Though It's not clear if you'd actually want your clients to be able to set `x` directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just have your getter initialize `_x` if it's `None`:

```
from random import random

class Object(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        if self._x is None:
            self._x = random()
        return self._x
```

Comment: or even `self._x = random() if self._x is None else self._x` ... which i think is marginally cooler ... but essentially the same :P +1

Comment: @JoranBeasley - yes, definitely much cooler, but the actual stochastic computation is about 20 lines, :p.